# How to change Allow sites to save and read cookie data (recommended) and/or Block third-party cookies

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've requirement to test webpages using Selenium with below cookies settings

```
1. Allow sites to save and read cookie data (recommended)

2. Block third-party cookies
```

I found link [how to disable cookies using webdriver for Chrome and FireFox JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18106588/how-to-disable-cookies-using-webdriver-for-chrome-and-firefox-java), which does setting at global level and not individual setting under Cookies.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on the driver. With Chrome and Firefox you can set the behavior by setting the preferences with the driver.

Preferences with Chrome to allow/block the cookies:

```
// allow all cookies
"profile.default_content_setting_values.cookies": 1  // 1:allow, 2:block 
"profile.block_third_party_cookies": false

// block third party cookies
"profile.default_content_setting_values.cookies": 1  // 1:allow, 2:block
"profile.block_third_party_cookies": true

// block all cookies
"profile.default_content_setting_values.cookies": 2  // 1:allow, 2:block
"profile.block_third_party_cookies": true
```

Preferences with Firefox to allow/block the cookies :

```
// allow all cookies
"network.cookie.cookieBehavior": 0

// block third party cookies
"network.cookie.cookieBehavior": 1

// block all cookies
"network.cookie.cookieBehavior": 2
```

To figure-out a preference, simply compare the preferences before and after changing the option manually in the target browser.

For Chrome the file is named `Preferences`. To get the path of this folder, navigate `about:config` with Chrome.

For Firefox, the file is named `prefs.js`. To get the path of this folder, navigate `about:profiles` with Firefox.

Comment: Can you please clarify how you got the values profile.XXX for chrome browser ?

Comment: I got them from the preference file named `Preferences` which is present in the profile folder (see about:config for the path). Compare the file before and after changing the settings manually in chrome (Menu/Settings/Advanced/ContentSetting/Cookies).

Comment: Thanks for detailed info.

Answer (score 4):

These setting have been [migrated to a new key](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/5da1ca03804fba9f861631a86cf8f10b1896ff66/chrome/browser/resources/settings/site_settings/constants.js#L78):

The new settings to block and manage third party cookies are:

```
// 1 = allow all cookies (default)
// 2 = block all cookies
"profile.default_content_setting_values.cookies": 1

// 0 = allow third party 
// 1 = block third party
// 2 = block third party in incognito (default)
"profile.cookie_controls_mode": 1
```