# System.InvalidOperationException : unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: DOMException error using Azure and Selenium through C#

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, azure-automation

I'm running tests on a Remote Machine through Azure daily scheduled run. Some of the tests are failing with below error log. How can I fix this ?

Note : I do not have method implementation of launching chrome driver as I am referencing dll of other solution which has abstract methods.

**Stack : NUnit, C#, Selenium, Visual Studio, Azure, log4Net**

> OneTimeSetUp:
>   Automation.Test.Framework.Models.Exceptions.AtGenericException : Error
>   initializing WebDriver Chrome
>   ----> System.InvalidOperationException : unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: DOMException: Failed to read the
>   'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this
>   document. at :1:1 (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.90)
>   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540470
>   (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91),platform=Windows NT
>   6.3.9600 x86_64)

Comment: Can you share the script code which is failing? Does the same tests fail in each run?

Comment: Found this on chromium: https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines/uncaught-securityerror-failed-to-read-the-localstorage-property-from-window-access-is-denied-for-this-document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
OneTimeSetUp: Automation.Test.Framework.Models.Exceptions.AtGenericException : Error initializing WebDriver Chrome 
System.InvalidOperationException : unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: DOMException: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document. at :1:1 (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.90) 
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540470 (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64)
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.36*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.36*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.36/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v63-65**

- You are using *chrome= 77.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v77.0.3865.40*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/77.0.3865.40/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome version 77**

So there is a clear mismatch between the *ChromeDriver v2.36* and the *Chrome Browser v77.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v78.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=78.0.3904.70/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 78.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v78.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/78.0.3904.70/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Comment: Upvote the answer if this/any answer is/was helpful to you for the benefit of the future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Guess you should changed the default Chrome capabilities to allow third-party cookies:

[Disabling Cookies in Webdriver for Chrome/Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32381946/disabling-cookies-in-webdriver-for-chrome-firefox)