# Selenium: "ElementClickInterceptedException", Element is not clickable because another element obscures it

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, scroll

I am trying to click on the "CSV" button at this website https://covid19-vaccine-report.ecdc.europa.eu/#6_Reported_data using `selenium`.

[image]

However, with the below code I am receiving the error `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <button class="dt-button buttons-csv buttons-html5" type="button"> is not clickable at point (464,600) because another element <div class="cckBannerInner"> obscures it`.

The code:

```
import os
import glob
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

# get directory of the current script
CURR_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
URL = 'https://covid19-vaccine-report.ecdc.europa.eu/#6_Reported_data'
ACCEPT_COOKIES_ID = 'cckAcceptCookies'
VACCINES_XPATH = '//*[@id="DataTables_Table_0_wrapper"]/div[5]/button[2]'

# before downloading new files, remove old ones
for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(CURR_DIR, "dataset_2021-W*")):
    os.remove(f)

# this will prevent opening browser window
# (https://stackoverflow.com/a/60627463/1979665)
options = Options()
#options.add_argument("--headless")

# (https://stackoverflow.com/a/18440478/1979665)
# To prevent download dialog
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2)  # custom location
profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', CURR_DIR)
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'text/csv')
# (https://stackoverflow.com/a/32416545/1979665)
profile.set_preference("network.cookie.cookieBehavior", 2)

# (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58727916/1979665)
browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile,
                            executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install(),
                            options=options)
browser.get(URL)
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 2000000)

# accept cookies
accept_cookies = browser.find_element_by_id(ACCEPT_COOKIES_ID)
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", accept_cookies)

# download vaccines as CSV
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, VACCINES_XPATH))).click()
browser.quit()
```

The XPATH of the button was taken with the copy XPath feature of the Firefox web developer console.

I have read many other suggested answers and tried their solutions but none worked.

I use JavaScript to accept the cookies (`browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", accept_cookies)`), in order for the banner to go away, because when I tried with other methods I received the error `could not be scrolled into view`.

Then I am using `WebDriverWait` to wait for the desired button to be clickable (with `element_to_be_clickable`).

When the code runs, I see what's happening in the browser window, and I do see that the cookie are accepted and the banner goes away. Then the page is scrolled down to the CSV button, but I receive the aforementioned error, like if the button is still hidden by the cookie banner.

The exact error (I repeat it down here), indeed refers to the cookie banner this way:

`selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <button class="dt-button buttons-csv buttons-html5" type="button"> is not clickable at point (464,600) because another element <p class="cckInform"> obscures it`

I also tried increasing the wait time up to `5000000` but it did not make any difference.

**WORKING CODE**

Thanks to [@Prophet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67705833) I was able to make it work. The trick was to scroll down the page until the button becomes visible and only then click on it.

I also removed the "accept coockie" part this way, which is great given that now I have to deal with only one element this way.

The updated working code:

```
import os
import glob
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

# get directory of the current script
CURR_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
URL = 'https://covid19-vaccine-report.ecdc.europa.eu/#6_Reported_data'
VACCINES_XPATH = '//*[@id="DataTables_Table_0_wrapper"]/div[5]/button[2]'

# before downloading new files, remove old ones
for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(CURR_DIR, "dataset_2021-W*")):
    os.remove(f)

# this will prevent opening browser window
# (https://stackoverflow.com/a/60627463/1979665)
options = Options()
#options.add_argument("--headless")

# (https://stackoverflow.com/a/18440478/1979665)
# To prevent download dialog
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2)  # custom location
profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', CURR_DIR)
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'text/csv')
# (https://stackoverflow.com/a/32416545/1979665)
profile.set_preference("network.cookie.cookieBehavior", 2)

# (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58727916/1979665)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile,
                            executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install(),
                            options=options)
driver.get(URL)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 2000000)
vaccines = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, VACCINES_XPATH)))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", vaccines)
vaccines.click()
driver.quit()
```

Comment: I tried your code on Chrome and it did download the csv file.

Comment: Can it be a browser related issue then? I have chosen FF because I know that it is installed on the server I am supposed to run this code from (in headless mode), and I am not sure I could ask to install other browsers in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following: scroll into view some other element that is below the desired button  so that the desired button will not be covered by the cookies banner and then try clicking the button.

```
national_references = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#national-references")))
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(national_references).perform()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, VACCINES_XPATH))).click()
```

**UPD**:
Since scrolling to the `national_references` was not possible since it `is out of bounds of viewport width (1366) and height (630)` according to the exception thrown when trying so scroll it into the view with `actions.move_to_element(national_references).perform()` we can scroll page down until `national_references` becomes visible.
Now we can successfully click the vaccines CSV button.

Comment: Thanks for trying to helping me! I tried but `actions.move_to_element(national_references).perform()` gives me the error `selenium.common.exceptions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Message: (837, 3218) is out of bounds of viewport width (1366) and height (630)`.

Comment: OK, If so try scrolling page down until that element is visible and the click the vaccines btn

Comment: Yeah, that's it! Thank you so much. I will update my question to provide the working code.
If you want, you could adapt your answer according to your recommendations and I would be happy to accept it;)